# NVL2 and not exists in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am pulling some records in table A from X table.
Now, I want to select records which are not available in table A but available in table B. But at the same time, I don't want to select records available in both tables.

Moreover,if a column in table A is null but the same column in the record in table B has value, I want to take that too.

Is it possible to do something like this in one statement ?

Comment: Please edit your question, show table DDL example table data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple set based operation. Relational databases are very good in that:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE b (id NUMBER);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (3);

SELECT id FROM b 
MINUS
SELECT id FROM a;

ID
2
```